# Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz. Generé este código en base a un video que encontré pero me da ese error. el generador de qr solo debe ser tx

Tags: c#, qrcode, generator

El error me lo lo da en el generador de Qr es para generar etiquetas de bienes inmuebles lo que debe contener son 4 caracteristicas pero al parecer son demaciados caracteres los que pongo en el txt. tambien el txt se pone de tamaño normal solo lo puedo hacer mas largo pero ancho no. Soy nuevo por eso me vase en ese video si alguien pudiese explicarme como arreglo ese error se lo agradeceria mucho

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Codigos_de_barras
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zen.Barcode.CodeQrBarcodeDraw mGeneradorQR = 
            Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeQr;
            pbCodigoQR.Image = mGeneradorQR.Draw(txtCodigoQR.Text, 300);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                string qr = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pbCodigoQR.Image);
                bitmap.Save(qr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Diego, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que uses la **librería Zxing** por las facilidades que ofrece en la generación y personalización de **códigos QR**. Una vez que hayas instalado esta librería ya sea desde **Nuget** o manualmente agregas las referencias necesarias en los **usings**:

```
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing.QrCode.Internal;
using ZXing.Rendering;
```

A continuación el código que bien podría escribirse en un botón:

```
BarcodeWriter br = new BarcodeWriter();
EncodingOptions encodingOptions = new EncodingOptions()
{
    Width = 200,
    Height = 200,
    Margin = 1,
    PureBarcode = false,
};

encodingOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);     
br.Options = encodingOptions;
br.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

br.Renderer = new BitmapRenderer()
{
    Foreground = Color.Black,
    Background = Color.White
};

Bitmap bitmap = br.Write("Hola Mundo");
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Aquí se crea el **objeto BarcodeWriter** que será el encargado de generar el **código QR** a partir del texto que se le indique. Posteriormente se configuran determinadas propiedades que en este caso son el ancho, el largo y el margen del **QR**(estas son mis configuraciones, tú bien puedes establecer otras a tu gusto), se establece un nivel de corrección alto para facilitar la lectura del **código QR**, ya que este puede tener imágenes incrustadas o no tener suficiente calidad, lo cual dificultaría la lectura en teléfonos más antiguos. Se especifica además el tipo de código de barras a usar que en este caso es **QR_CODE**(recuerda que un **código QR** es un **código de barras bidemensional**), posteriormente se especifican los colores a usar, que en este caso serían blanco para el fondo y negro para dibujar el **QR**. A continuación se usa el **método Write** para generar el **QR** a partir del texto **"Hola Mundo"**, este método crea un **Bitmap** con el **QR** ya dibujado, finalmente este **Bitmap** se muestra en un **PictureBox**.

**Nota**: Esta solución es una alternativa a la que tu implementas ya que usamos diferentes librerías, te toca a ti decidir cual librería usar, en lo personal yo te recomiendo **ZXing**.